# Services Docker swarm : (wsl2) can't accessible since windows

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have using docker in wsl2 environnement and since windows environnement i call my service(navigator) docker mode swarm but actually i have access problem.

In fact if i test `docker-compose up --build` then i had not problem to access container.
But if use docker swarm mode with `docker stack deploy` to try to access my services i cannot access.

For example :

In ubuntu wsl2:
Node server:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).json({
        "msg":"Server running !!!"
    })
});

app.listen(4000, (req, res) => {
    console.log("Server running on port 4000");
})
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  server_node:
    image: localhost:5000/server_node
    ports:
      - 5000:4000
```

In windows
For redirection request to ubuntu environnement
powershell:

```
 ssh -L 5000:localhost:4000 user@localhost -N
```

Comment: you dont need to do any ssh tunneling when using wsl2.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the app to run on 0.0.0.0 as opposed to localhost.

```
app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Server running on port 4000");
})
```

Comment: Thank you for you help but i have the same problem.
In powerShell ```channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused```